# execute two process in two cmd window sequentially quote conflict

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run `echo hallo` in first cmd window and I want that cmd window to pop up another instance of cmd that will execute `echo world` after `echo hallo` finished (with success or failure) and I want both cmd windows to stay opened ever after both processes completed

and to do this entire thing I'll run and `cmd.exe` from my program

right now I am using 
`cmd /K start cmd.exe /K "echo hallo & start cmd.exe /K echo world"`
and its working. and these two quotes are mandatory, otherwise it doesn't work

**The Problem:**

the two executables I'll runn in two command prompts may have spaces inside it So I have to guard them and their arguments in `"` and that will conflict with the enclosing quotes at top level. as I don't see it handles embedded quotes properly.

```
windows>cmd /K start cmd.exe /K "echo hallo & start \"cmd.exe\" /K echo world"
windows>cmd /K start cmd.exe /K "echo hallo & start ""cmd.exe"" /K echo world"
windows>cmd /K start cmd.exe /K "echo hallo & start 'cmd.exe' /K echo world"
```

none of these three works

Answer (score 0):

The /k needs to be part of the quoted string.
If you are trying to do what I think you are doing, try nesting the quotes like so:

```
cmd /K start cmd.exe /K "echo hello & start ""cmd.exe" /k" echo world"
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid quotes in file name use it's **8.3 alias**, such as EXECUT~1.EXE.

You can get the alias with
DIR /X "executable with spaces inside.exe"